# Vue2 : Make Page Fade In with "appear" transition and still use routing transition too

Tags: css, css-transitions, vuejs2

I was trying to do a page fade in when my app initially loads using appear; however, I am already using a routing css animation that does a fade in and fade out when going from page to page, but it still leaves me with an abrupt display of my page when it initially loads. So far, my attempts to add another transition tag around the routing transition in a outer nested way has failed. It still loads with an abrupt display of page. Any suggestions?

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <v-app>
            <main> 
              <transition  name="appearPageFadeIn" appear><!-- new appear tag -->


                   <cq-nav-mobile></cq-nav-mobile>

                   <cq-nav-desktop></cq-nav-desktop>



                       <transition name="interPageFadeOutIn" mode="out-in">
                            <router-view></router-view>
                       </transition>



                   <cq-footer></cq-footer>

                </transition>
            </main>

        </v-app>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- CSS -->

    /* appear page animation */



.appearPageFadeIn-appear {
    opacity: 0;
}

.appearPageFadeIn-appear-active {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

/* inter page routing animation */

.interPageFadeOutIn-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.interPageFadeOutIn-enter-active {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.interPageFadeOutIn-leave {
    opacity: 1; //default
}

.interPageFadeOutIn-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post your css for the transition?

Comment: Hi @whoacowboy . Thanks for your response. I have updated my question here with the new css and transition tag I am trying to use. When I nest the transition, it suggests that I use transition group, but I don't think that is what I want. I don't have a list of different elements, but two different types of animations on different elements with some overlap

Comment: There is a lot it could be. What I find mostly is that your main div doesn't have a height when you are animating it in. What I imagine is that the main div fades in. Then the router-view fades in. After the router-view fade is complete it has a height and then the main div has a height, so it appears to jump. Try not animating the router view and see if you can get the outer transition to work. If you want to post some more code I can look at it.

Comment: when I say abruptly, it isn't anything except an opacity problem. It just goes from 0 to 1 instantly. There is no height issue. I added all my css classes above now.

Comment: just got it.  This worked!       .appearPageFadeIn-enter {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .appearPageFadeIn-enter-active {
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }